# How can use source control in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, redgate

I use SQ Server 2012 and want to active source control on it. I want to use `Redgate SQL Source Control` for this purpose. When I Install `Redgate Source Control 3` buttons and menu on `SSMS 2008 R2` Change and add commands Source Control and button to it. but in `SSMS 2012` no changed applied.

Comment: If you want a source version control system try `git`; if unrelated to your question,, remove the *version-control* tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search about `Redgate`.
for add redgate source control to SSMS 2012 must be use updated version of SQL Server Source Control.

`Redgate SQL Source Control 3.0.13.4214`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Source Control is not a source control system. It is a shim that creates sql scripts from a database and submits the scripts to source control systems, and it does come with a config file for Git.

The SQL Source Control add-in *should* appear in SSMS 2012. If there is no evidence of it in the form of menu items, first try reinstalling it.

You *may* have issues if you have .net 4.5 beta installed, though. I don't believe SQL Source Control supports that.